# Get the name of other Users through relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration

I have a model Arrangement and a migration consists of:

```
Schema::create('arrangements', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('acceptor')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

The thing I can get the Username from the relationship like the following:

```
$arrangement->user->name
```

And I can get the id of the acceptor like the following:

```
$arrangement->acceptor
```

But I want to get the name of the acceptor, and if it's possible I want to access other properties of the acceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$table->integer('acceptor')->unsigned();
```

to:

```
$table->integer('acceptor_id')->unsigned(); //schema will be more intuitive
```

In your `Arragement` model add relationship as follows:

```
public function acceptor()
{
    // I assumed that you acceptor is a reqular user
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'acceptor_id');
}
```

Then you can access acceptor this way:

```
$arragement->acceptor->name;
```